# How to make background image fixed using css and HTML?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I have a section in which I have  added a background image, now I want this background image to stick at the same position in all devices like this below

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far

HTML

```
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="main-block_inner">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.capgemini.com/"> My app </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="py-5 text-center container">
      <h1 class="headers">Some headers gooes here </h1>
      <div class="row py-lg-5 content">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 mx-auto">
          <h1 class="fw-light">Album example</h1>
          <p class="lead text-muted">Something short and leading about the collection below—its contents, the creator, etc. Make it short and sweet, but not too short so folks don’t simply skip over it entirely.</p>
          <p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Main call to action</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">Secondary action</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here css

```
.main-block{
     background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/B6xfnvz/falka-1.png);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: 265px 0px;
     background-size: 1085px 1016px;
     height: 1080px;
}
 .main-block_inner{
     max-width: 816px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 1080px;
     padding-right: var(--bs-gutter-x, .75rem);
     padding-left: var(--bs-gutter-x, .75rem);
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-top: 30px;
}
 .content{
     border: 2px solid red;
}
 .headers{
     margin-bottom: 120px;
}
```

**Live demo**: [live demo](https://codepen.io/makumba/pen/gOxEvGY?editors=1100)

What do I need to do to get what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Add `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: That does not make any difference if you make the screen smaller (i.e. access on another divice). That only influences the scroll behaviour. That does not seem to be what the OP is after, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
background-position: 265px 0px;
```

Into this:

```
background-position: center center;
```

Or if you want to go fancy:

```
background-position: calc(50% + 1px) calc(50% + 1px);
```

Change the pixels according to your taste/desire.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

'position: fixed;'
OR 'position: relative' with the other code mentioned above if you wanted to be fixed relatively to the device mentioned.

Comment: In this particular case it is about css background properties like `background-attachment: fixed`. However, fixed or sticky positionings are good solutions if your background element is a rather 'decoupled' a html element – so just providing a background context and not containing any other content/child nodes that might expand it's initial boundaries.